# how to configure Single event receiver for multiple streams/dynamic stream name in wso2 DAS?

Tags: wso2, wso2-das, wso2-esb

I have configured JMS receiver in WSO2 DAS something like below xml. Now I am configuring receiver xml file for each stream. I see there is no configuration difference except stream name change (streamName="TABLE_NAME"). Is there any way I can use single event receiver for multiple streams to avoid duplicate code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<eventReceiver name="divolte_events_data_receiver" statistics="enable"
trace="enable" xmlns="http://wso2.org/carbon/eventreceiver">
<from eventAdapterType="jms">
    <property name="transport.jms.DestinationType">queue</property>
    <property name="transport.jms.Destination">MyQueue</property>
    <property name="java.naming.factory.initial">org.wso2.andes.jndi.PropertiesFileInitialContextFactory</property>
    <property name="java.naming.provider.url">repository/conf/jndi.properties</property>
    <property name="transport.jms.SubscriptionDurable">false</property>
    <property name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName">QueueConnectionFactory</property>
    <property name="transport.jms.UserName">admin</property>
    <property encrypted="true" name="transport.jms.Password">***</property>
</from>
<mapping customMapping="disable" type="json"/>
<to streamName="TABLE_NAME" version="1.0.0"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible with DAS as receivers are bound to streams and the flow. For JMS it looks like same but generally there are other receiver types which requires its own receiver. Ex:- In Http receivers different endpoints will be created for each receiver where as JSON event structure is based on the stream bound to the receiver